# single page app generating blank

Tags: ios, cordova, ruby-on-rails-4.2

After having built a project with phone gap and dictated an iOS version

```
phonegap build ios
```

launching the project with Xcode states `build succeeded` and returns the pre-configured image and text.

Launch the upstream rails server `rails s` and the application at localhost:3000 runs. Modifying the `index.html` page with the following:

```
<html>
    <head>

<script type="text/javascript">     
  function onBodyLoad()     
  {              
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);         
    window.location.href = "http://localhost:3000/";     
   }     
   function onDeviceReady()     
      {          }     
</script>     
    </head>
<body onload="onBodyLoad()">   </body>
</html>
```

as well as both `config.xml` files (at root of project **and** that within `platforms/ios/myapp_ios` with

```
 <access origin="http://localhost:3000/" />
```

returns a blank page.  Tried with an external link leading to the same blank behaviour.  What went wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

In this context, localhost will be the phone device or emulator that the PhoneGap app is running on.  You will want to change that for the IP address of your machine that the Rails server is on, even if it is the same machine that the emulator is running the PhoneGap app on.

Furthermore you would need to change your config.xml access element to use the same IP address you use in your app, and you may also need to add a Content Security Policy meta tag in your PhoneGap app index.html to allow content from the outside.  There's a detailed blog post on that [here](http://moduscreate.com/cordova-5-ios-9-security-policy-changes/).  If using iOS 9, also pay attention to the App Transport Security settings, as you may need to set an exception in your project's -Info.plist to handle non SSL content loads.

What are you trying to achieve here however, reloading the entire page remotely isn't a good idea with PhoneGap as you will lose all the plugin benefits etc as your new page will clobber the one that is bundled with your app.  What you want to do is load data from remote servers into templates bundled with your app in the PhoneGap www folder, or do the same with page snippets from remote servers.

Comment: `You will want to change that for the IP address of your machine` I have attempted the following four addresses localhost:3000, 127.0.0.1:3000, and isp generated IP addresses 94.xxx.yyy.103 ,  94.xxx.yyy.103:3000.  Also added `<allow-navigation href="http://*/*" />` to both config.xml files (still not certain which one), as well as `<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'"/>` to the index.html ...  to the same result.

Comment: as to the third paragraph, I (may) understand what could be the problem, but I'm trying to reach the functioning `hello world` phase...

Comment: From error logs, after `com.main_user.myapp_ios was installed` some SpringBoard errors `could not find icon for representation and `assertiond[2948]: assertion failed:`.  However the last log entry does state `Finished load of: file:///Users/[...]/myapp_ios.app/www/index.html`